# Anti-aliased Arc Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, antialiasing

I am trying to code a simple circle timer in Python using Pygame. 
At the moment it looks like this:
[image: Timer]

As you can see, the blue line is very wavy and has white dots in it. I am achieving this blue line by using pygame.draw.arc() function, but it is not anti-aliased and looks bad. I would like it to be anti-aliased, but gfxdraw module which should let me achieve this, doesn't support arc width selection. Here's code snippet:

```
pygame.draw.arc(screen, blue, [center[0] - 120, center[1] - 120, 240, 240], pi/2, pi/2+pi*i*koef, 15)
pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(screen, center[0], center[1], 105, black)
pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(screen, center[0], center[1], 120, black)
```

Answer (score 2):

I did it creating the arc with a polygon.

```
def drawArc(surface, x, y, r, th, start, stop, color):
    points_outer = []
    points_inner = []
    n = round(r*abs(stop-start)/20)
    if n<2:
        n = 2
    for i in range(n):
        delta = i/(n-1)
        phi0 = start + (stop-start)*delta
        x0 = round(x+r*math.cos(phi0))
        y0 = round(y+r*math.sin(phi0))
        points_outer.append([x0,y0])
        phi1 = stop + (start-stop)*delta
        x1 = round(x+(r-th)*math.cos(phi1))
        y1 = round(y+(r-th)*math.sin(phi1))
        points_inner.append([x1,y1])
    points = points_outer + points_inner        
    pygame.gfxdraw.aapolygon(surface, points, color)
    pygame.gfxdraw.filled_polygon(surface, points, color)
```

The for loop could certainly be created more elegantly with a generator, but I am not very sophisticated with python.

The arc definitely looks nicer than pygame.draw.arc, but when I compare it to the screen rendering on my mac, there is room for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any pygame function that would solve this problem, meaning you basically have to program a solution yourself (or use something other than pygame), since `draw` is broken as you've noted and `gfxdraw` won't give you the thickness.

One *very ugly* but simple solution is to draw multiple times over the arc segments, always slightly shifted to "fill in" the missing gaps. This will still leave some aliasing at the very front of the timer arc, but the rest will be filled in.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame.gfxdraw
import math

# Screen size
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 350
SCREEN_WIDTH = 500

# Colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREY = (150, 150, 150)
RED = (255,0,0)


 # initialisation
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# We need this if we want to be able to specify our
#  arc in degrees instead of radians
def degreesToRadians(deg):
    return deg/180.0 * math.pi

# Draw an arc that is a portion of a circle.
# We pass in screen and color,
# followed by a tuple (x,y) that is the center of the circle, and the radius.
# Next comes the start and ending angle on the "unit circle" (0 to 360)
#  of the circle we want to draw, and finally the thickness in pixels
def drawCircleArc(screen,color,center,radius,startDeg,endDeg,thickness):
    (x,y) = center
    rect = (x-radius,y-radius,radius*2,radius*2)
    startRad = degreesToRadians(startDeg)
    endRad = degreesToRadians(endDeg)

    pygame.draw.arc(screen,color,rect,startRad,endRad,thickness)


# fill screen with background
screen.fill(WHITE)
center = [150, 200]
pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(screen, center[0], center[1], 105, BLACK)
pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(screen, center[0], center[1], 120, BLACK)

pygame.display.update()

step = 10
maxdeg = 0

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    maxdeg = maxdeg + step
    for i in range(min(0,maxdeg-30),maxdeg):
        drawCircleArc(screen,RED,(150,200),119,i+90,max(i+10,maxdeg)+90,14)  
        #+90 will shift it from starting at the right to starting (roughly) at the top
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(2)  # ensures a maximum of 60 frames per second

pygame.quit()
```

Note that I have copied `degreesToRadians` and `drawCircleArc` from https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~pconrad/cs5nm/08F/ex/ex09/drawCircleArcExample.py

I do not generally recommend this solution, but it might do in a pinch.

Comment: That looks way better, but still isn't perfect. I will try to google or think about other possible solutions

Comment: Easiert way if you need to use pygame would be to just do it in a graphics program and blit the counter steps from a spritesheet. If you only need in it a handful places, a hand-written hack is probably not worth the effort.

Comment: why not draw the next segment and then apply a flood fill?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre how would you do the flood fill? Afaik pygame doesn't have a built-in function for that. You could use `pygame.gfxdraw.filled_polygon()`, but that would mean calculating the points for the polygon arc segment beforehand, which seemed arduous.

Comment: In that case I would perform a forest-fire algorithm for the flood fill, but that could be cpu-consuming, unless it is pre-computed as you suggested earlier.

Comment: Is there a graphics library you would recommend as an alternative to pygame?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, some pygame rendering functions do indeed suck, so you can achieve something like this with `PIL` instead.

```
pie_size = (40, 40)  # defining constants
pil_img = PIL.Image.new("RGBA", pie_size)  # PIL template image
pil_draw = PIL.ImageDraw.Draw(pil_img)  # drawable image
pil_draw.pieslice((0, 0, *[ps - 1 for ps in pie_size]), -90, 180, fill=(0, 0, 0))  # args: (x0, y0, x1, y1), start, end, fill
```

This will create a PIL shape. Now we can convert it to pygame.

```
data = pil_img.tobytes()
size = pil_img.size
mode = pil_img.mode
pygame_img = pygame.image.fromstring(data, size, mode).convert_alpha()
```

But don't forget to `pip install pillow` and

```
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageDraw
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is really old, but why not try to draw pies instead. For example draw a pie, then an unfilled circle as the outside ring and then a filled circle as the inside and another unfilled circle as the inside ring.

So `pie -> unfilled circle -> filled circle -> unfilled`.

The order is somewhat arbitrary but if u still have this problem give it a try. (Btw I haven't tried it but I think it will work)

Answer (score 0):

For my own uses, I wrote a simple wrapper function, and to deal with the spotty arc drawing, I used an ugly loop to draw the same arc several times.

```
def DrawArc(surface, color, center, radius, startAngle, stopAngle, width=1):
    width -= 2
    for i in range(-2, 3):
        # (2pi rad) / (360 deg)
        deg2Rad = 0.01745329251
        rect = pygame.Rect(
            center[0] - radius + i,
            center[1] - radius,
            radius * 2,
            radius * 2
        )

        pygame.draw.arc(
            surface,
            color,
            rect,
            startAngle * deg2Rad,
            stopAngle * deg2Rad,
            width
        )
```

I'm aware this is not a great solution, but it works alright for my uses.

An important note is I added that "width -= 2" to hopefully preserve the intended size of the arc at least a little more accurately, but this results in increasing the minimum width by 2.

In your case, you might want to consider doing something more to fix the issues this results in.

Comment: You should use `math.degrees` or `math.radians` for both better readability and higher accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

If the start and end aren't all that important, one can create many circles following an arc trajectory and when done ie small circles drawn 360 time, you finally have a big circle with no wavy effect:

**MWE:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pygame
import math

# Initialize pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the screen size
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))

# Set the center point of the arc
center_x = 200
center_y = 150
arc_radius = 100
circle_radius = 6

# Set the start and stop angles of the arc
start_angle = 0
stop_angle = 360
angle_step = 1

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Clear the screen
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    # Draw the overlapping circles
    for i in range(start_angle, stop_angle, angle_step):
        angle = math.radians(i)
        x = center_x + arc_radius * math.cos(angle)
        y = center_y + arc_radius * math.sin(angle)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, "red", (int(x), int(y)), circle_radius)
    
    # Update the display
    pygame.display.flip()
    
pygame.quit()
```

Having a `start_angle` and `stop_angle` of `0` to `360` respectively yields a fill circle with an output:

[image]

To change it to a 1/3 of a circle, one would change the `stop_angle` from 360 to `120` (1/3 x 360 = 120) and this would then yield:

[image]