# An arc that follows my mouse but stays on the circle

Tags: python, image, pygame, mouse, draw

I am trying to make the arc follow my mouse while staying on the circle path.

I do not know why it is not working.

When I run it, it just create a pygame white screen with no error.

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import division 
from math import atan2, degrees, pi
import math
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
pygame.display.set_caption("globe")
CENTER = (400, 400)
RADIUS = 350

running = True

def drawCircleArc(screen,color,center,radius,startDeg,endDeg,thickness):

    (x,y) = center
    rect = (x-radius,y-radius,radius*2,radius*2)
    startRad = math.radians(startDeg)
    endRad = math.radians(endDeg)
    pygame.draw.arc(screen,color,rect,startRad,endRad,thickness)


while running:

  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
        running = False

  mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

  relx = mouse[0] - CENTER[0]
  rely = mouse[1] - CENTER[1]
  rad = atan2(-rely,relx)
  rad %= 2*pi
  degs = degrees(rad)


  screen.fill((152,206,231))

  drawCircleArc(screen,(243,79,79),CENTER,RADIUS, degs + 90,degs + 100 ,10)


  pygame.draw.circle(screen, (71,153,192), CENTER, RADIUS)
  pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPsn2.png)
[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A5OU.png)

What I really want is the following picture
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the follow will do what you want. I fixed two problems:

1. You were drawing the graphics in the wrong order and covering up the short reddish arc (they need to be drawn from back to front), and
2. The two literal values you were adding to the calcuated `degs` angle were too large.

I also made a several other changes that weren't strictly needed, including reformatting the code follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines and adding a `pygame.time.Clock` to slow down the refresh rate to something I though was more reasonable.

```
from __future__ import division
from math import atan2, degrees, pi
import math
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
pygame.display.set_caption("globe")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60  # Frames per sec
CENTER = (400, 400)
RADIUS = 350

running = True

def draw_circle_arc(screen, color, center, radius, start_deg, end_deg, thickness):
    x, y = center
    rect = (x-radius, y-radius, radius*2, radius*2)
    start_rad = math.radians(start_deg)
    end_rad = math.radians(end_deg)
    pygame.draw.arc(screen, color, rect, start_rad, end_rad, thickness)

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    relx = mouse[0] - CENTER[0]
    rely = mouse[1] - CENTER[1]
    rad = atan2(-rely, relx)
    degs = degrees(rad)

    screen.fill((152,206,231))
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (71,153,192), CENTER, RADIUS)
    draw_circle_arc(screen, (243,79,79), CENTER, RADIUS, degs-10, degs+10, 10)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

Here's what it looks like running

[image: screenshot of script running showing arc and mouse position]

Comment: Also how do you remove the blue particle from the red block which changes along the circle?

Comment: It's an artifact of how thick arcs are being rendered. Apparently pygame simulates them by drawing a concentric series of 1-pixel wide arcs each with slightly different radius. These thin lines are pixelated and the blue you see is the from the big blue circle underneath them. Only way I can think of to get rid of it would be to create a polygon that represents the outer edges of the thick arc and filling it — which would be much slower and take a lot more code to implement (relatively speaking).

Comment: The graphics in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143135/anti-aliased-arc-pygame), illustrate the effect more clearly. (Note the answers, too).

Comment: Also, my initial issue was that I could not open the pygame window. But it seems it is because of the IDE I am using. I am using spyder for python.